# How to import a package located in a different local directory in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter project, and I need to import a package called "mbcl" into my project. The package's pubspec.yaml is located at the path ~/lib/mbcl/pubspec.yaml, while my project's pubspec.yaml is located at ~/app/pubspec.yaml.

I'm not sure how to include this external package in my Flutter project. Can someone please guide me on how to properly import the "mbcl" package while keeping my project organized and efficient? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

following [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages) I tried adding this to the project's pubspec.yaml,

```
dependencies:
  ...
  mbcl:
    path: lib/mbcl/
```

I was expecting this should work, as mbcl is located in a directory next to the app.
here is my directory structure,

contents of the project dir mathebuddy

```
mathebuddy
│
├── app
│     │
│     ├─ pubspec.yaml(1)
│     
├── lib
│     │
│     ├─ mbcl
│         │      
│         ├─pubspec.yaml(2)
```

Comment: You need to specify either an absolute path or a path relative to the current package's path.  For example: `path: ../lib/mbcl`

Comment: That works!, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. There's one minor thing though:

> Relative paths are allowed and are considered relative to the directory containing your pubspec.

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages

Your point of reference is your app's `pubspec.yaml`. So the relative path to the `mbcl` package would be `../lib/mbcl` like so:

```yaml
dependencies:
  mbcl:
    path: ../lib/mbcl
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this had worked for me!